# iOS - How to Pass AppDelegate's ManagedObjectContext to UIViewController that comes from NavigationView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm struggling with a Core Data concept and I need some clarification.

I'm using Storyboards and I have 2 view. The first view is embedded in a navigation controller, and the second view is just a UIViewController that comes from a modal segue.
In AppDelegate I am passing the managedObjectContext to the first view using this code:

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
JobListTableViewController *jltvc = (JobListTableViewController *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
jltvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

The problem is that now I need to also pass the managedObjectContext from AppDelegate to my second view, but I dont know how to get a hold of it.
Doing this, just fails since there's no index 1:

```
AddJobsViewController *ajvc = (AddJobsViewController *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];
```

I can't post a screenshot of my storyboard since I dont have enough stackoverflow reputation :(

Any help on this core data/delegation issue will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your **JobListTableViewController** or **AddJobsViewController**, you can hold reference of **AppDelegate** like this.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
jltvc.managedObjectContext = app.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Thanx. I've read that option in several places and I've seen mixed answers.
Some people say this is a great design approach and others say this is bad practice.
Do you have any idea of what could be a down side of this approach or why some people hate it?

Comment: Accessing frequently AppDelegate may be one issue. But if it is not loaded then you can create private AppDelegate Variable inside your JLTVC or AJVC. There is noting bad in this approach.

Comment: Ok thanx. I'll use that approach then.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is that you don't pass the context from view controllers. Rather than that create a new context and fetch the entities from the new context. The downside of passing the same context is that if a same entity is modified in two different places, you have to manage the merge conflict. Context is like a scrap pad that can be used to either make changes and save or else discard the context if you don't want changes. So you can create a local context every time you want to modify the entities and either save or discard it depending on your needs and hence avoiding conflicts.
what i prefer is a 3 tier system like this

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) backgroundMasterContext // this context is used to save data in core data
{
    if(!_backgroundMasterContext) {
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if(coordinator) {
            _backgroundMasterContext =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            [_backgroundMasterContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }
    }
    return _backgroundMasterContext;
}

-(NSManagedObjectContext*) mainContext // this context is a read only context which is used everytime you want to read the entities
{
    if (!_mainContext) {
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator) {
            _mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
            [_mainContext setParentContext:self.backgroundMasterContext];
        }
    }

    return _mainContext;
}

-(NSManagedObjectContext*) createWriteContext // this context is used everytime you want to edit an entity 
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [newContext setParentContext:self.mainContext];
    return newContext;
}
```

And for saving i call this method

```
- (void) saveAllWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*) writeContext
                    success:(DMSuccessBlock)success
                    failure:(DMFailureBlock)failure
{
    BOOL b = NO;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if([writeContext hasChanges]) {
        b=[writeContext save:&error];

        if(b) {
            NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = [writeContext parentContext];
            if(parentContext) {
                [parentContext performBlock:^{
                    [self saveAllWithContext:parentContext success:success failure:failure];
                }];
            } else {
                if(success)
                    success();
            }
        } else {
            if(failure)
                failure(error);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(success)
            success();
    }
}
```

This method updates main context and background master context.

Hope it helps :)